# Cannot set the width of a button in XML android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to set up some buttons on a tablet app.  In order to be configurable, we have 6 buttons that get set by the database to be visible or GONE.  In our current app, we have all but one of the buttons set to be GONE.  The problem is that I would like to set the width of the remaining button to be less than the width of the screen, but I cant figure out a way to do that.

Here is the original XML layout (which sets up 2 rows of 3 buttons of equal width):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layoutSubjectMenuMain"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/backgroundcolor"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutButtons"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutButtons_Row1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_margin="5px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50px"
        android:layout_marginRight="50px"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
            android:layout_marginRight="5px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Infusionxxxxxx"
            android:textSize="20sp" 
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
            android:layout_marginRight="5px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Bleed Episodexxx"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="10px"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
            android:layout_marginRight="5px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Untoward Eventxxxx"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutButtons_Row2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_margin="5px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
            android:layout_marginRight="5px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Medication / Therapyxxxx"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
            android:layout_marginRight="5px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Non-Study Visitxxxx"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
            android:layout_marginRight="5px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Questionnairexxxx"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

If I try setting the width attributes of the buttons to say 100dp, nothing happens. Removing the weight attribute does nothing to reduce the width. If I try to set the width attribute of the linear layouts does nothing to reduce the width.

What can we do to change the width of the remaining button (@id\btn1)  It currently takes up the whole width and we want to reduce it.

Comment: Try changing the button layout_width to wrap_content in addition to removing the weight.

Comment: So, I wasted my (valuable to me) time trying to help you?

Comment: Setting the layouts to GONE or INVISIBLE did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Set `layout_width = "0dp"`
Then use `layout_weight` field under `Button`. You can give the proportion each Button will take like the following:

```
android:layout_weight = "1"
```

Get the screen dimensions and set the Button width accordingly:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Note that getSize() was introduced in API level 13.

Answer (score 0):

you may use this in your oncreate method:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
this.ancho = metrics.heightPixels;
this.largo = metrics.widthPixels;
```

this is going to give the width of the screen and with that, you can put the propeties of your button under java code.

:D

Comment: Excellent idea.  Too bad it doesn't fix my problem.  <3

Answer (score 0):

This layout will work, if you set the visibility to View.INVISIBLE, instead of GONE.  You can control the distance between the buttons by setting either the margin or padding of the LinearLayout for each button.  You can control the distance between the two rows by changing the padding or margins of the LinerarLayout of each each row.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layoutSubjectMenuMain"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutButtons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutButtons_Row1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/jj"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Infusionxxxxxx"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/kk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="invisible" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bleed Episodexxx"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="invisible" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Untoward Eventxxxx"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutButtons_Row2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/aa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Medication / Therapyxxxx"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Non-Study Visitxxxx"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Questionnairexxxx"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```